# How do you PRACTICALLY use lazy loading in your application?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I see a lot of places where expert delvelopers advice to **LAZY load** the persisted entities in order to save memory.

The concept is quite clear: it is **useless** to load tons of information **you're not going to use**.

However, in my everyday experience to apply this best practice comes up to be not trivial at all. I mean, **if I define a dependency**, let's say a one-to-many relation between a `DEPARTMENT` and an `EMPLOYEE`, it is very likely **I'll need** the list of employees while handling the `Department` in my business logic.
This thing is common and I find myself to use EAGER loading in the most of the cases.

From a programmatically point of view, the best I can do is to ship my Dao methods with a flag like that

`public Department getDepartment(String departmentName, boolean eagerly)`

where the `eagerly` attribute set to `true` triggers a full loading of the Department (which is LAZY loaded by default. I call the `getEmployees()` inside the transaction to load the employees list).

How do you handle the problem? Do you feel confortable with the LAZY loading? If so, am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

According to the @Ayman explanation I'd like to discuss the following approach, with hibernate.

```
    public class Node {
        private Node parent;
        private Set<Node> children;

        public getParent(){
            if(parent==null)
                return Hibernate.initialize(parent);
            return parent;
        }

        public getChildren(){
            if(children==null)
                return Hibernate.initialize(children);
            return children;
        }
    }
```

Is it an acceptable implementation? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: I suspect the advice is use lazy loading where you can.  This doesn't mean lazy loading is useful in all cases.  In trading system for example, you prefer eager loading and worry less about much memory costs. e.g. 32 GB costs about $300 these days.

Comment: Think that if you do not use lazy loading, a query for the list of enterprises will load also all of its departments, which will load a list of all of its employees, wich will load... Deciding when it is worth doing a eager loading depends of the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation.  I do not recommend adding the eagerly flag as it exposes internal working of your library.  It should be transparent to the user.

The way I usually do it is in the classes.  The department will have a list of employees.  When reading the department, just read the dept table and leave the emp array as null.  Then when you have to access the employees, see if the list was loaded or not.  Should be fairly easy to implement and shields the library user from knowing the internals of the lib.

Comment: I really like your approach, but I ask myself if it's pushed beyond the boundaries of hibernate domain. I mean, with your solution it is worthless even to conceive an EAGER approach. You just load things as you need them. Maybe I'm wrong but isn't Hibernate duty to take care of separation between classes and persistence?

Comment: I was not referring to Hibernate at all.  Just a general comment that applies to lazy loading and evaluation.  If you are using a framework, then by all means stick to what the frameworks is designed to do, especially if it is well established one, like Hibernate.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I deliberately assumed you referred to Hibernate because I'm using it! XD

Comment: I want to discuss your solution in an hibernate fashion. Please find it in the EDIT section of the question.